# Cant find class library package when building in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I created a class library in Visual Studio 2015 which project.json is:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }  
}
```

When I build it I am not able to find the DLL or the Nuget package.

How can I create a Nuget package when I build the solution?

Comment: did you use NuGet to install and or include the package into your solution..? in regards to the newtonsoft.Json or whatever current Json library package you want installed into your current project

Comment: @MethodMan: He isn't asking to parse JSON; that is his project fine.  He's asking about DNX.

Comment: Yes, I am asking how to build the packgage of the class library ... I think I must use dnx. not sure how

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/52